# Switch Statement within For Loop Failing to Check Variable at Certain Values

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-physics, sfml

As the title suggests, I am experiencing problems with a `switch` statement failing to check the `i` variable within a `for` loop a certain values. The Boolean function below simulates oriented bounding box collision between two sprites, with the `i` variable representing each face of the oriented bounding box. However, when the function returns `false`, `i` is only checked at values `0` and `1`, and when the function returns `true`, `i` is only checked at values `2` and `3`.

I don't know whether or not it's the `for` loop or the `switch` statement that is causing this error, and I've double-checked to see if the collision works on all the faces of the oriented bounding boxes, to which I can confirm that it indeed works perfectly. Any form of assistance would be gladly appreciated!

Collision.cpp:

```
bool Collision::orientedBoundingBoxTest(const sf::Sprite &object1, const sf::Sprite &object2, int object1Width, int object1Height, int object2Width, int object2Height)
{
    /*Variables assigned and declared here*/

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        float faceX = collisionObject1.getPoint(i).x - collisionObject1.getPoint((i + 1) % 4).x;
        float faceY = collisionObject1.getPoint(i).y - collisionObject1.getPoint((i + 1) % 4).y;

        float perpendicularAxisX = -faceY;
        float perpendicularAxisY = faceX;

        float normalizedAxisLength = sqrt(perpendicularAxisX * perpendicularAxisX + perpendicularAxisY * perpendicularAxisY);
        perpendicularAxisX /= normalizedAxisLength;
        perpendicularAxisY /= normalizedAxisLength;

        float object1Min = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), object1Max = -object1Min;
        float object2Min = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(), object2Max = -object2Min;

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            float object1Projection = (perpendicularAxisX * (collisionObject1.getPoint(j % 4).x + collisionObject1.getPosition().x) + perpendicularAxisY * (collisionObject1.getPoint(j % 4).y + collisionObject1.getPosition().y)) / (perpendicularAxisX * perpendicularAxisX + perpendicularAxisY * perpendicularAxisY);
            object1Min = min(object1Projection, object1Min);
            object1Max = max(object1Projection, object1Max);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            float object2Projection = (perpendicularAxisX * (collisionObject2.getPoint(j % 4).x + collisionObject2.getPosition().x) + perpendicularAxisY * (collisionObject2.getPoint(j % 4).y + collisionObject2.getPosition().y)) / (perpendicularAxisX * perpendicularAxisX + perpendicularAxisY * perpendicularAxisY);
            object2Min = min(object2Projection, object2Min);
            object2Max = max(object2Projection, object2Max);
        }

        switch (i) //Switch statement failing to check "i" variable at certain values
        {
        case 0:
            deltaY = -(object1Max - object2Min);
            break;
        case 1:
            deltaX = object1Min - object2Max;
            break;
        case 2:
            deltaY = object1Min - object2Max;
            break;
        case 3:
            deltaX = -(object1Max - object2Min);
            break;
        }

        if (! (object1Max >= object2Min && object1Min <= object2Max))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Engine.cpp:

```
void Engine::physics(sf::RenderWindow& _window)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (collision.orientedBoundingBoxTest(collisionArray[i].collisionObjectSprite, player.playerSprite, collisionArray[i].width, collisionArray[i].height, player.width, player.height))
        {
            currentCollisionObjectIndex = i;
            player.hitTest = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            player.hitTest = false;
        }
    }

    /*Additional code here*/
}
```

Comment: http://sscce.org/ please

Comment: What are you doing to determine that `i` is "only checked" at certain values?  Obviously if the function returns `false`, it is exiting the `for i` loop early so the later values of `i` may be skipped.

Comment: `deltaX` and `deltaY` are not even used or defined in this function. It's really not clear what this code snippet is doing.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that when `i` returns `true`, it does not check for the `0` and `1` values, but it appears that I am wrong.

Comment: I guess the problem now is that when the `for` loop iterates, only the final values of `deltaX` and `deltaY` are taken. `deltaX` and `deltaY` are both `int` variables defined in a separate header file. They determine the difference between the distance of two oriented bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your conclusion is wrong, put `cout << i << endl;` between `case`s, and ensure about your results.

I'm sure each `0..3` will be meet on each iterate ot `i`, unless the `return` statement be invoked.

```
   switch (i)
    {
    case 0:
        deltaY = -(object1Max - object2Min); cout << i << endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        deltaX = object1Min - object2Max; cout << i << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        deltaY = object1Min - object2Max; cout << i << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        deltaX = -(object1Max - object2Min); cout << i << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect the error is the `return false;` in the first function or the `break;` in the second.

Comment: `i` is indeed being incremented now, and I have to agree with Mooing Duck on this case because now when the statement returns `false`, the `for` loop only iterates up to `1` before restarting the entire loop.